# Removing an element during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am showing a bigger size image when mouse is hovered over a thumbnail. Both the thumbnail image and the bigger size image are created dynamically, I am using `clip` effect to show the bigger size image.
When mouse is moved away from the thumbnail the bigger size image must be removed. Here is my code.

```
$(".uploadThumb").live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
           if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
                var src = $(this).prop("src");
                var img = $("<img class='big_thumb' src='"+src+"' width='400'/>");
                $(this).after(img);
                img.hide().show("clip", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1000);
              } else {
                  $(this).siblings(".big_thumb").remove();
              }
});
```

When I move the mouse over the thumbnail the bigger image is appearing correctly, and if I wait for the animation to complete and then move away the mouse from the thumbnail it is getting removed perfectly.
**But, If I move away the mouse before the animation(`clip`) is complete the bigger image is not removed**

**[Here is a demo of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/bSSVP/)**

Is there any solution or I have to remove the animation :((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you really need to use [`sibilings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method?

You just can write:

```
$(".big_thumb").remove();
```

And everything should work.

See updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/antyrat/bSSVP/7/).

Comment: Ahh I am so embarrassed. I thought that I need to remove the corresponding image only, but I didn't realized that at a time only one bigger image will be visible. Tnxx a lot.